# Python startswith does NOT match the same string

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

So, I can run the code if I use the code block within the function where the variable list is first defined, however when I pass the variable to another function and run startswith(), it is returning false!

```
def lambda_handler(event, context): 

    test = ['2', 'Snapshot-Only2019-10-07T06-08-43.522172Dev/']
    name_of_snapshot_folder = test[1]
    total_instances = int(test[0])

    print('name_of_snapshot_folder : {0}'.format(name_of_snapshot_folder))

    start_status_check(name_of_snapshot_folder, total_instances) 

def start_status_check(name_of_snapshot_folder, total_instances): 

    try: 
        print('Type of total instance inside start status check : {0}'.format(type(total_instances)))
        snap_list = [] 
        count = 0 
        print('Type of snapshot folder is :{0}'.format(type(name_of_snapshot_folder)))
        print('Total instances are :{0}'.format(total_instances))
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        new_name = str(name_of_snapshot_folder).strip()
        print('type pf new name: {0}'.format(type(new_name)))

        for i in my_bucket.objects.all():
            print('Printing i inside my bucket loop: {0}'.format(i.key))
            print('Snapshot-Only2019-10-07T06-08-43.522172Dev/ff'.startswith(new_name))

            if(i.key.startswith(new_name) and i.key.endswith('.txt')): 
                count += 1 
                print(count)
                print('Printing i :{0}'.format(i))
        print("count value {0}, true or false is? {1} :".format(count, count == total_instances))
        if count == total_instances: 
            print('testing phase') 
            #client = boto3.client('lambda') 
            print('Total files matches total instances, invoking status check function') 
            check_backup_status(total_instances, name_of_snapshot_folder) 
        else: 
            print('Inside codepipeline continued execution')
```

startswith() should return True, however its returning false in the second function

Comment: You're passing your arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: You are my friend in need! THANK YOU!
That did solve the problem in test phase, however when I run it in lambda I had same order, and its still returning False

Comment: @user2357112 

I have same order in my original code, when I use this with codepipline, this does not return True
In the above test code its fixed.

Comment: @david-bob first, insulting people for downvoting is not a good way to get help. Although I agree that downvoting without a comment as to _why_ it was downvoted is not helpful at all. Second, Iam _guessing_ that it was downvoted because your question does not isolate the problem and does not include a MCVE. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help the helpers, and in turn avoid further downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

strip() did the job! so simple to fix